# Basic Workflow question

Tags: workflow, automation

Say I schedule a time-dependant workflow for 5 hours before Account.dateTimefield

If I create a new account and upon creation Account.dateTimefield is only two hours away, will the workflow fire? Or does the workflow only run specifically 5 hours in advance?

Comment: It will fire.Better you can test using 5 mins instead of keep waiting for 5 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RobertBarnett states, the answer is YES. This is covered in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en_US):

> If a workflow rule has a time trigger set for a time in the past,
>   Salesforce queues the associated time-dependent actions to start
>   executing within one hour. For example, if a workflow rule on
>   opportunities is configured to update a field 7 days before the close
>   date, and you create an opportunity record with the close date set to
>   today, Salesforce starts to process the field update within an hour
>   after you create the opportunity.

And, as @RobertBarnett states, you could easily test this yourself by adding an Account with a dateTimeField only 5 minutes in advance of `now` - then look in `Setup | Monitoring | Time-Based Workflow` to see the scheduling of the workflow - within 1 hour, it will execute